# Why is IPSR in hardfault in main

Tags: c, embedded, cortex-m, stm32h743

Working with STM32H743 (cortex-m7 CPU)
My OS wrapper crashes at init because it checks if IPSR value is 0 (ST CMSIS V2 with FreeRTOS)
So I added this

```
int main(void)
{
    volatile uint32_t testvar1;
    testvar1 = __get_IPSR();
```

I read `3` and looking at [this](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0646/b/The-Cortex-M7-Processor/Programmers-model/Core-registers?lang=en#BABGBIBI)
It means I am in Hardfault, but it's the first lines of my main
Why would I read hardfault there ?

Comment: When not in abort mode the value of *PSR registers is not meaningful.

Comment: so you think I should remove the IPSR tests ?